# Why I can't open the cmd window on my Win10?

Tags: windows-10

When I press Windows+R and input cmd to open the command line, the cmd window doesn't appear, only the cmd icon appears on the taskbar.
How can I fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Once you have opened it, you might type <kbd>ALT+SPACE</kbd>. This shortcut opens the menu for minimising and maximising but also for moving a window. It is possible that your command window is somewhere present on another second screen (which is not there anymore, but Windows seems not to realise that), so using that shortcut you can move your window till you see it again.

Comment: Thanks, it works? But evetime I start the cmd, I need to repeat this operation, how to make it appear automatically when I start it?